# Use max on each element of a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, max

```
> x <- array(-10:10, dim=c(4,5))
> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  -10   -6   -2    2    6
[2,]   -9   -5   -1    3    7
[3,]   -8   -4    0    4    8
[4,]   -7   -3    1    5    9
```

How do I apply "max(x, 0)" to each element so that I get this matrix:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    2    6
[2,]    0    0    0    3    7
[3,]    0    0    0    4    8
[4,]    0    0    1    5    9
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `pmax`:

```
pmax(x,0)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    0    0    0    2    6
#[2,]    0    0    0    3    7
#[3,]    0    0    0    4    8
#[4,]    0    0    1    5    9
```

Comment: This did not work for me. I did `> x=read.csv(...)  > x2 = sapply(data,atanh)  > pmax(x2,-20)` but this produced a vector of `-20`'s instead of a matrix of the original dimensions. (Note that `> class(x2)
[1] "matrix"` eventhough `> class(x)
[1] "data.frame"`) @Chase his solution did work.

Comment: @TimKuipers `pmax` preserves the `dim` of the object - you're probably leaving out a step or your `x2` is not rectangular

Comment: Ah no. The mistake I made was that since my matrix was really big, I tried looking at just a part of it by doing `x2[1:10]` instead of `x2[1:10,]`. I'm sorry!

Comment: @TimKuipers np, glad you figured it out

Answer (score 5):

You can use R's indexing function `[` to do this directly:

```
x <- array(-10:10, dim=c(4,5))
x[x < 0] <- 0
```

This works because `x < 0` creates a logical matrix output:

```
x < 0

     [,1] [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
[1,] TRUE TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[2,] TRUE TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[3,] TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[4,] TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

And the resulting matrix is:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    2    6
[2,]    0    0    0    3    7
[3,]    0    0    0    4    8
[4,]    0    0    1    5    9
```

The timing between the two methods is surprisingly similar. Here's a larger example illustrating the comparable timings:

```
xbigC <- xbigE <- matrix(sample(-100:100, 1e8, TRUE), ncol = 1e4)
system.time(xbigC[xbigC < 0] <- 0)
 #--- 
  user  system elapsed 
   4.56    0.37    4.93 
system.time(xbigE  <- pmax(xbigE,0))
#---
   user  system elapsed 
   4.10    0.51    4.62 
all.equal(xbigC, xbigE)
#---
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: @ManInMoon - yep, no worries. The direct indexing approach will be more flexible in that you can create more complicated conditions with other logical operators. For this task, it seems `pmax()` is ever so slightly more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the order of the arguments to `pmax()` affects the class of what is returned when the input is a matrix:

```
pmax(0,x)
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

pmax(x,0)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    2    6
[2,]    0    0    0    3    7
[3,]    0    0    0    4    8
[4,]    0    0    1    5    9
```